# Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS wont shutdown completely

Tags: shutdown

Sometimes, my computer doesn't shut down properly. The screen goes black, the keyboard stops responding, and I have to hold down the power button to force it to shut down. I tried looking for solutions online, but couldn't find the reason behind this issue.

Here's some information that might help:

```
last -Fxn2 shutdown reboot
```

> reboot   system boot  6.5.0-25-generic Fri Mar 15 13:20:54 2024 still running  
>  shutdown system down  6.5.0-25-generic Fri Mar 15 13:17:02 2024 - Fri Mar 15 13:20:54 2024  (00:03)
> wtmp begins Tue Feb 27 17:12:21 2024

```
grep -iE 'shutdown|reboot|poweroff' /var/log/syslog
```

> Mar 15 13:20:57 saba sbkeysync[661]:      from /usr/share/secureboot/updates/dbx/dbxupdate_x64.bin 
> Mar 15 13:20:57 saba sbkeysync[661]:      from /usr/share/secureboot/updates/dbx/dbxupdate_x64.bin 
> Mar 15 13:20:57 saba sbkeysync[661]:      from /usr/share/secureboot/updates/dbx/dbxupdate_x64.bin 
> Mar 15 13:20:57 saba systemd[1]: Started Unattended Upgrades Shutdown.
> Mar 15 13:20:59 saba cron[1098]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
> Mar 15 13:21:32 saba systemd[1189]: Reached target Shutdown.

If I understand correctly, the shutdown process took three minutes, which seems abnormal.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your shutdown command?

Comment: I use GUI to shutdown. ("Power Off/Logout" Button)

Comment: Please Set your uefi to Default after you write your own Changes on a Paper.

Comment: @nobody Do you recommend resetting my BIOS settings after noting down my changes?

Comment: @muddu yes i See a Firmware Upgrade.